# Group by and find amount difference sql same table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I have table like this below :

[image]

And i want the result like : sum the amount group by date and find the difference between the result

[image]

Comment: which version of my sql are you using?

Comment: Im using Server version: 10.3.23-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8.0 then you can use `lag()` to achieve expected output.

```
select
    date,
    amount,
    coalesce((amount - last_val), amount) as diff
from
(
  select
      date,
      amount,
      lag(amount) over (order by date) as last_val
  from
  (
      select
          date,
          sum(amount) as amount
      from myTable
      group by
          date
  ) subq
) subo
order by
    date
```

Comment: it says : #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: @MuhammadEkkiIrfansyah try now.

Comment: still got the same error  #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: why is that bro ? i dont get it ... teach me ... :)

Comment: maybe its the lag() function is that it ? just guessing ...

Comment: @MuhammadEkkiIrfansyah should work now. try it out.

Comment: It work bro,,,, tell me... why this query work ? whats wrong with the prev query ?

Comment: just want to know ... and try to climb that mountain...

Comment: Thanks bro ... I have a lot to learn... magic bro ...